# How to temporarily disable a Junit test from running?

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I have the following Junit test class

```
package Md5Tests;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import timebackup.*;

/**
 *
* @author jack
*/
public class PathNodeToXmlTest {

public PathNodeToXmlTest() {
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
}

@Test
public void createXml() {
    PathNode root = new PathNode(true, "docs", "0");
    root.addPathNode(new PathNode(true, "docs sub folder", "1"));
    root.addPathNode(new PathNode(false, "docs sub file", "2"));
    PathNodeToXml xmlCreator = new PathNodeToXml(root);
    System.out.println(xmlCreator);
}
}
```

I am now trying to temporarily stop the test `createXml()` from being run by the test runner. I have tried adding the `@Ignore` annotation right before the `@Test` annotation however the compiler throws an error saying that it can't find the symbol for `@Ignore`. I am using the NetBeans Ide.

Anyone have any ideas either how to prevent the compile error, or another way to temporarily prevent a JUnit test from running?

Comment: Comment out Test annotation, e.g. `//@Test`

Comment: Just to be sure: add `import org.junit.Ignore;` to import list to use `@Ignore`

Comment: @DarshanMehta It didn't work, I am still getting the compiler error

Comment: @defaultlocale It worked like a charm, Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[@Ignore](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html) annotation is in a package `org.junit` so you need to add import statement

```
import org.junit.Ignore;
```

or

```
import org.junit.*;
```

Next time you have a problem like this you can just google class name (e.g. `junit @Ignore`) go to the [documentation page](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html) and check package name.

In NetBeans you can use "Source -> Fix Imports" command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) and IDE will try to resolve necessary imports automatically.